# 3D animation of a vector field (ParaView)

Tags: matlab, visualization, vector, paraview

I am trying to create an animation of a 3d vector field in ParaView.

All my data is in three matrices (201 x 201 x 201) corresponding to vectors components in x,y,z directions. And it's calculated in MATLAB. 
If I do:

```
B = cat(4,Bx,By,Bz);
B = permute(B,[4 1 2 3]);
fid = fopen('Bvec.raw','w'); fwrite(fid,B,'float'); fclose(fid);
```

I can load Bvec.raw into ParaView and visualise the vector field at one instant of time.

Now, how would I go about making an animation if I had say 100 (Bx, By, Bz) triples at different instants of time? Without creating 100 different raw files and loading them into paraview by hand.

ALSO, I'm not set on using paraview, it's just the first software I tried, so if you think there's an easier/better/ more competent way of going about it I'd appreciate suggestions.

Comment: This question would be better asked on the [ParaView mailing list](http://www.paraview.org/mailman/listinfo/paraview). You can absolutely do this in ParaView, but it's off-topic here.

Comment: Someway you will need to have this info, 100 files or a huge file with the 100 timesteps. What's the difference?